# Finding the angle between a tangent line to a function and the x axis.

Tags: calculus, functions, angle

If we have a function $f(x)>0$ that has the following property:

$$f''(x)>0, $$
where this property only holds for $x>0$. What is the angle $\theta$ that a tangent line to the function makes with the $x$-axis, given that the tangent line must pass through the origin, and the point of tangency with $f(x)$ occurs in the first quadrant?

**Here is what I have done:**

Let the tangent line be $y=mx$, where $m>0$

So we let the two functions equal each other, and take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ to give us another equation as well, since their slopes will be equal at the intersection. Now we have the two equations:

$$f(x)=mx$$
$$f'(x)=m$$

Now after solving for $m$, I obtained the following result:

$$m=f'\left(\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right)$$

Which will leave us with:

$$\theta=tan^{-1}\left(f'\left(\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right)\right)$$
to the $x$-axis.

Are my steps in solving this correct? Will this leave us with an angle independent of x if we plug in a function that satisfies the conditions?

Comment: You haven't used that $f''$ is positive.

Comment: @ajotatxe the fact that f''(x) is positive can only be used to be certain that a tangent line to f(x) that goes through the origin and occurs in the first quadrant is possible, right?

Comment: Even isn't. I think that it's a typo.

Comment: @ajotatxe Sorry, can you be more clear on what you mean here? Where is the typo?

Comment: The question is very unclear. The angle can be any $\theta \in \left( 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ for a suitable function $f$, so it's not possible to give a single number as an answer. So maybe $\theta$ should be expressed in terms of something - but in terms of what? Also for some functions $f$ the angle $\theta$ doesn't even have to exist.